# what is the specific reason to differentiate functions and methods in Go?

Tags: function, go, methods, syntax

I have read about what is the difference between functions and methods. I have gone through some previous answers on stack-overflow. However, I could not understand why exactly they are kept different. According to my understanding: whatever can be done using methods can also be done using functions in Go. I know methods are also functions. To further clarify my questions and I have added an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    a, b int
}

func (p *Point) sumM() int {
    return p.a + p.b
}
func sumF(p *Point) int {
    return p.a + p.b
}

func (p *Point) mulM(n int) int {
    return (p.a + p.b) * n
}
func mulF(p *Point, n int) int {
    return (p.a + p.b) * n
}

func main() {
    p := Point{2, 3}
    fmt.Println("sumM is: ", p.sumM())
    fmt.Println("sumF is: ", sumF(&p))
    fmt.Println("mulM is: ", p.mulM(2))
    fmt.Println("mulF is: ", mulF(&p, 2))
}
```

where **M** and **F** represent method and function respectively.

I want to know if I am missing something; if there is some authentic reasoning behind these different implementations. e.g. pros and cons for each.

Comment: In most languages, methods are related to class even if they are still function. So it's a matter of scope (when you say method, it belong to a class and is available only per object instance) and evolution (in a class, some methods are private --internal-- whereas others are public and can be redefined with heritage games) Of course, my answer isn't Go specific, I just wanted to give some hints.

Comment: Go's [interface](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) feature only works with methods.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips from [Golang Methods](https://www.callicoder.com/golang-methods-tutorial/):

- A method is just a function with a receiver argument.
- Methods help you write object-oriented style code in Go.
- Method calls are much easier to read and understand than function calls.
- Methods help you avoid naming conflicts. Since a method is tied to a particular receiver, you can have the same method names on different receiver types.

[The thumb of the rule is](https://medium.com/@ishagirdhar/methods-vs-functions-in-golang-c60586bfa6b4) that do not define methods if:

- Dependency on the state is not required
- You can perform this function on any type that implements a specific interface which means you don’t need to restrict this function to belong to a specific type.